# Failed to apply plugin [class 'org.gradle.api.plugins.scala.ScalaBasePlugin']: Gradle v2.13

Tags: java, scala, gradle, build

Trying to build my project with **gradle 2.13**.

**Getting Error:**

```
MUSGM186035-835:c gm$ gradle build
Version suffix : -6

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/gm/IdeaProjects/repo/a/b/c/build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':b:c:QGInitiator'.
> Failed to apply plugin [class 'org.gradle.api.plugins.scala.ScalaBasePlugin']
> A dependency must not be empty

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or 
--debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.397 secs
```

**My build.gradle file looks like,**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin:'scala'//Line with error

ourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.1"
}
```

This project is part of another project which has other gradle files. But I am not buling the parent project. Not sure what is happening with my dependency.

**Stacktrace:**

```
   Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: A dependency must not be empty
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskDependency.addValue(DefaultTaskDependency.java:122)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskDependency.add(DefaultTaskDependency.java:115)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$11.run(AbstractTask.java:323)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskMutator.mutate(TaskMutator.java:37)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.dependsOn(AbstractTask.java:321)
at org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.IdeaPlugin$_configureForScalaPlugin_closure8.doCall(IdeaPlugin.groovy:229)
at org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.IdeaPlugin$_configureForScalaPlugin_closure8.call(IdeaPlugin.groovy)
at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:67)
at org.gradle.internal.Actions$FilteredAction.execute(Actions.java:205)
at org.gradle.listener.ActionBroadcast.execute(ActionBroadcast.java:39)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:165)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:159)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:142)
```

Comment: Use `-s` to get the full stacktrace of the error and post it here if you don't see the error yourself then.

Comment: Added --stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying the `idea` plugin to the root plugin. I'm not exactly sure what's going on, but that should solve the issue.

Comment: `idea` is a plugin for the IntelliJ right? I really don't need that for the building. Anyways tried using it. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Hm, strange. The error is in [this line](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/REL_2.13/subprojects/ide/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/plugins/ide/idea/IdeaPlugin.groovy#L229), and according to the stacktrace there is an empty list of dependencies given. While I'm not sure why there are `ideaModule` tasks actually, adding the `idea` plugin to the root project should at least add the `ideaProject` task and thus make the error go away.

Comment: Ah, maybe you added it too late. Add the `idea` plugin before the `scala` plugin and see whether the error vanishes then.

Comment: I added it before `scala` only.

Comment: Hm, very strange then. Can you provide the project, so that I can have a look personally?

Comment: It was because of the dependency between `idea` and `scala` plugins only. I had a gradle file which had `apply plugin` defined in the wrong sequence.